Unknown resource type: 'registry_value' with puppetlabs-registry installed
I'm new to puppet and attempting to use the chocolatey module for windows clients.  I've installed all of the module dependencies:
root@puppet:/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/chocolatey/manifests# puppet module list --environment production
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/site-modules
├── adhoc (???)
├── profile (???)
└── role (???)
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules
├── puppetlabs-acl (v5.0.0)
├── puppetlabs-apt (v9.4.0)
├── puppetlabs-chocolatey (v8.0.0)
├── puppetlabs-concat (v9.0.2)
├── puppetlabs-facts (v1.4.0)
├── puppetlabs-inifile (v6.1.1)
├── puppetlabs-powershell (v6.0.0)
├── puppetlabs-puppet_agent (v4.19.0)
├── puppetlabs-pwshlib (v1.1.1)
├── puppetlabs-reboot (v5.0.0)
├── puppetlabs-registry (v5.0.1)
├── puppetlabs-ruby_task_helper (v0.6.1)
└── puppetlabs-stdlib (v9.6.0)
/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules (no modules installed)
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules (no modules installed)

For whatever reason when I try to run puppet agent --test --trace --debug --verbose
I get the following error:
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Unknown resource type: 'registry_value' (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/chocolatey/manifests/install.pp, line: 38, column: 3) on node desktop-pmmjds3.wftigers.org
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/indirector/catalog/rest.rb:48:in `rescue in find'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/indirector/catalog/rest.rb:9:in `find'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/indirector/indirection.rb:230:in `find'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/configurer.rb:731:in `block in retrieve_new_catalog'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:518:in `block in thinmark'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/3.2.0/benchmark.rb:311:in `realtime'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:517:in `thinmark'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/configurer.rb:730:in `retrieve_new_catalog'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/configurer.rb:84:in `retrieve_catalog'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/configurer.rb:269:in `prepare_and_retrieve_catalog'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/configurer.rb:430:in `run_internal'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/configurer.rb:341:in `run'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/agent.rb:85:in `block (6 levels) in run'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/context.rb:64:in `override'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:288:in `override'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/agent.rb:84:in `block (5 levels) in run'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/3.2.0/timeout.rb:189:in `block in timeout'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/3.2.0/timeout.rb:196:in `timeout'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/agent.rb:83:in `block (4 levels) in run'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/agent/locker.rb:23:in `lock'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/agent.rb:73:in `block (3 levels) in run'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/agent.rb:164:in `with_client'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/agent.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in run'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/agent.rb:129:in `run_in_fork'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/agent.rb:68:in `block in run'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:174:in `controlled_run'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/agent.rb:49:in `run'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application/agent.rb:437:in `onetime'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application/agent.rb:394:in `block in run_command'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/context.rb:64:in `override'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:288:in `override'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application/agent.rb:391:in `run_command'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:423:in `block in run'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:706:in `exit_on_fail'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:423:in `run'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/command_line.rb:145:in `run'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/command_line.rb:79:in `execute'
C:/Program Files/Puppet Labs/Puppet/puppet/bin/puppet:5:in `<main>'
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I thought that if the registry module was installed, the resource type should not be unknown.

puppetlabs-registry should indeed be providing the registry_value resource type. Moreover, the module metadata should be reliable for specifying module dependencies, and your puppet module --list appears to show that all modules' dependencies are satisfied.

Is it possible that this client is requesting / assigned to a different environment than production?  If so, then it might be that puppetlabs-chocolatey is available in that environment, but puppetlabs-registry is not. I'm not immediately sure how such a misconfiguration would arise in practice, but it is technically possible.

So this is where my ignorance is going to come into play...  If I'm editing the sites.pp file in the production environment, and the output of that agent changes to reflect that, wouldn't it have to be in the production environment?

I read this: https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/environments_creating.html
I looked at the puppet.conf file, and there isn't a statement for environment, so I think it should still be the default, which is production.  Right?

production is the default environment, but there are at least three ways in which an environment can be chosen for a node, so not having one set in puppet.conf is not a sure sign.  However, if modifying a manifest in the production environment causes a client's catalog to change, then that's a very strong sign that that client is in the production environment.

Ok...  So....  I'm an idiot.  I don't know why, but apparently, the server needed to be restarted after I installed the module?  I had rebooted before I installed them, but couldn't figure out why a reboot would be required for what is effectively reading a file.  Lesson learned.  Thanks for your help, John!

It sounds like you may have experienced an effect of environment caching.

It turns out that I needed to reboot the server after I installed the module.  I don't understand why, maybe it is some sort of cataloging that happens on some modules.  I didn't have to restart for chocolatey to be recognized and useable...
John mentioned it might be environment caching, which I don't recall changing from the default, but that at least points in a direction.
Thanks, John!
